# How can I add a new filter field to the Run Allocations by Projects screen

Tags: acumatica

I'm customizing the 'Run Allocations by Projects' screen to add another field to the header / filter section, and use that to filter the grid data.  I've managed to add a PXString field for 'status', using the Project Status field as a template:

```
public class AllocationFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<AllocationFilter>
{
    #region UsrStatus
    [PXString(1, IsFixed = true)]
    [ProjectStatus.List()]
    [PXDefault(ProjectStatus.Active)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status", Required = true, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual string UsrStatus { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrStatus : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

I then add that field to the definition of the 'Items' view by extending the BLC as follows (showing the added line separated from the block in the middle):

```
public class AllocationProcessByProjectExt : PXGraphExtension<AllocationProcessByProject>
{
    public PXCancel<AllocationFilter> Cancel;
    public PXFilter<AllocationFilter> Filter;
    public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<PMProject, AllocationFilter, LeftJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<PMProject.customerID>>>,
            Where2<Where<Current<AllocationFilter.allocationID>, IsNull, Or<PMProject.allocationID, Equal<Current<AllocationFilter.allocationID>>>>,
                    And2<Where<Current<AllocationFilter.projectID>, IsNull, Or<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Current<AllocationFilter.projectID>>>>,
                    And2<Where<Current<AllocationFilter.customerID>, IsNull, Or<PMProject.customerID, Equal<Current<AllocationFilter.customerID>>>>,

                    **And2<Where<Current<AllocationFilterExt.usrStatus>, IsNull, Or<PMProject.status, Equal<Current<AllocationFilterExt.usrStatus>>>>,**

                    And2<Where<Current<AllocationFilter.customerClassID>, IsNull, Or<Customer.customerClassID, Equal<Current<AllocationFilter.customerClassID>>>>,
                    And2<Where<Current<AllocationFilter.customerClassID>, IsNull, Or<Customer.customerClassID, Equal<Current<AllocationFilter.customerClassID>>>>,
                    And2<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>,
                    And<PMProject.nonProject, Equal<False>,
                    And<PMProject.isTemplate, Equal<False>,
                    And<PMProject.baseType, Equal<PMProject.ProjectBaseType>>>>>>
                    >>>>>> Items;
```

This works beautifully to filter the grid, until I try to actually process selected (checked) lines, at which point I get the following error.  I cannot figure out what's causing it / what's missing:

[image]

Any thoughts on why this would happen?  Do I need to add something to the Business logic in order to use a User field?

Thanks much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `aspx` page check, that you have `CommitChanges` set to `true.`

```
using PX.Objects.PM;
using static PX.Objects.PM.AllocationProcessByProject;
namespace ExampleDB.DAC
{
public sealed class AllocationFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<AllocationFilter>
{
    #region UsrStatus
    [PXString(1, IsFixed = true)]
    [ProjectStatus.List()]
    [PXDefault(ProjectStatus.Active, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status", Required = true, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public string UsrStatus { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrStatus : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
}
```

In the graph extension

```
using ExampleDB.DAC;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CT;
using PX.Objects.PM;
namespace ExampleDB
{
public class AllocationProcessByProjectExt : PXGraphExtension<AllocationProcessByProject>
{
    public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<PMProject, AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter, LeftJoin<AllocationProcessByProject.Customer, On<AllocationProcessByProject.Customer.bAccountID, Equal<PMProject.customerID>>>
        , Where2<Where<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.allocationID>, IsNull, Or<PMProject.allocationID, Equal<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.allocationID>>>>
            , And2<Where<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.projectID>, IsNull, Or<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.projectID>>>>
                ,And2<Where<Current<AllocationFilterExt.usrStatus>, IsNull, Or<PMProject.status, Equal<Current<AllocationFilterExt.usrStatus>>>>
                , And2<Where<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.customerID>, IsNull, Or<PMProject.customerID, Equal<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.customerID>>>>
                    , And2<Where<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.customerClassID>, IsNull, Or<AllocationProcessByProject.Customer.customerClassID, Equal<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.customerClassID>>>>
                        , And2<Where<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.customerClassID>, IsNull, Or<AllocationProcessByProject.Customer.customerClassID, Equal<Current<AllocationProcessByProject.AllocationFilter.customerClassID>>>>
                            , And2<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>, And<PMProject.nonProject, Equal<False>, And<PMProject.baseType, Equal<CTPRType.project>>>>>>>>>>> Items;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry - in the last line in the BQL view: "And<PMProject.baseType, Equal<CTPRType.project>>>>>>>>>>> Items;" - what is CTPRType?  I can't find any reference to that at all...

Comment: What is your Acumatica version?This code working in 19R2 release

Comment: Version 17.209.0028 - although I got it to work anyway.  My mistake was using reference 'using static PX.Objects.PM.AllocationProcess;' instead of 'using static PX.Objects.PM.AllocationProcessByProject;'.   Once I fixed that, it worked fine.

Thanks much for your help!